# Google maps API not working on my Ionic Cordova app while using mobile hotspot

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, mobile

I have an Ionic app which Google maps API and shows your current location on a map and it works fine while on wifi and even using mobile data. However, when I make the phone into a mobile hotspot using mobile data the Google maps API doesn’t load on the Ionic app even though other features such as login work on the app. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: plz someone help me i'm crying in the corner of the room trying to fix this. I know ionic is shit but you gotta help a brother our here.

Comment: on god Ionic is so shiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiit